Existence of solutions to irregular and unbounded ODE (or additive noise SDE)
The problem
Consider an $\alpha$-Hölder continuous function $B$ (for $\alpha\in(0,1/2)$) with $B(0)=0$ but whose level sets $\{t\ge 0:B(t)=x\}$ have Lebesgue measure zero for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Fix $\delta>0$ and consider the ODE
$$ U'(t)=\frac{\delta}{B(t)+U(t)}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}(B(t)+U(t)),\quad \text{Lebesgue-a.e. and}\quad U(0)=0.$$
I would like to know if this ODE has a (unique) solution in the sense of Carathéodory (i.e. an absolutely continuous function $U$ whose density satisfies the above equation). If it is of any use, as you might have guessed, I am interested in the case where $B$ is a Brownian path (or Wiener process).
I am aware of a few results ensuring the existence of solutions for the ODE
$$ U'(t)=f(t,U(t)),\quad \text{Lebesgue-a.e. and}\quad U(0)=0, $$
assuming that $f$ is measurable and bounded (via Girsanov's theorem to establish weak solutions and Veretennikov's proof of strong uniqueness to the SDE, so that Yamada and Watanabe's argument ensures strong existence and uniqueness) or if $f\in L^4(\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R},\mathrm{Leb})$ (which is not the case for my function $f(t,x)=\delta/(B(t)+x)$). Now, I could consider the regularised SDE
$$ U'_c(t)=\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(B(t)+U_c(t))}{|B(t)+U_c(t)|+c},\quad \text{Lebesgue-a.e. and}\quad U_c(0)=0,$$
for some $c>0$ to apply the standard theory (here, $\mathrm{sgn}$ denotes the sign function with convention $\mathrm{sgn}(0)=0$). However, this regularisation is not monotone in $c$, so approximation arguments as $c\to0$ appear difficult. It would be desirable (but unclear) if even $$ c\mapsto\int_0^t\frac{1}{|B(s)+U_c(s)|+c}\mathrm{d}s $$ is monotone.
Local solutions for other initial conditions
As Jade rightly pointed out, if we considered the initial condition $U(0)=u_0\ne 0$, we could define a solution up to the first time $U(t)=-B(t)$ but it is unclear if such a solution can be extended beyond this point.
A slightly different equation
It is funny to note that, if $R\ge 0$ is a Bessel process of dimension $2\delta+1$ with $\delta>0$ and satisfying
$$ dR(t)=dB(t)+\frac{\delta}{|R_t|}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}(R_t)dt, \quad R(0)=0,$$
then the process $U(t)=R(t)-B(t)=\int_0^t\frac{\delta}{|R_s|}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}(R_s)ds$ is absolutely continuous and satisfies
$$ U'(t)=\frac{\delta}{|B(t)+U(t)|}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}(B(t)+U(t)),
\quad\text{Lebesgue-a.e. and}\quad
U(0)=0,
$$
which is remarkably similar to what I asked above. (I realise that the absolute value is rarely written since $R$ is positive, but I wanted to make this distinction here since above I considered a possibly negative solution.)

The specific condition $U(0)=0=B(0)$ is only problematic because it guarantees $|U'(t)|\to \infty$ with $t\to 0$. More generally, any point where $U(t)=-B(t)$ is problematic. However, any initial value $U(t_0)\neq -B(t_0)$ guarantees a unique solution on some interval neighborhood of $t_0$, and that interval is indefinitely extensible at least until reaching a boundary point where $U(t)=-B(t)$. Where $B$ is Wiener process however, almost surely there will be such a boundary point, and it's unclear how (or if) we can extend beyond such boundaries.

The restriction $U(0)=0=B(0)$ is not sufficient to give a unique solution, and this primarily has to do with the singularity indicated by $|U'(t)|\to \infty$ at the point $t=0$. More concerningly, even if two solutions agree entirely for all $t\leq 0$, it's possible that they still disagree for all $t>0$, and this happens even for simple examples. For instance, take the function $B(t) = 2^{3/2}\sqrt{\lvert t\rvert}$, then over the domain $t\geq 0$ we have two possible solutions given by $U_1(t) = (2-\sqrt{2})\sqrt{t}$ and $U_1(t) = (-2-\sqrt{2})\sqrt{t}$. Both those functions admit the same extension to $t<0$ given by $U_j(t) = -\sqrt{|2t|}$, hence we have $U_1$ and $U_2$ agreeing entirely for all $t\leq 0$ but suddenly disagreeing for all $t>0$.
The above problem extrapolates to any case where there's a point at which $U(t_0)+B(t_0)=0$. Essentially, the singularity prevents the behavior of $U$  for $t<t_0$ to influence the behavior of $U$ for $t>t_0$. Because of this, it may be preferable to consider those branches as unrelated, and only try to construct solutions to $U$ on intervals where $U(t_0)+B(t_0)\neq 0$ always holds.
Under the requirement that $U(t)+B(t)\neq 0$, and in the case where $B$ is modeled by the Wiener process as you mentioned, there almost surely does not exist any solution $U$ with domain being all Real numbers. Proving this is trivial once we notice that the solutions to $U$ are necessarily monotonic. That is, since $U(t)+B(t)$ is continuous but never zero, then it's either always positive or always negative, hence $U'$ is either always positive or always negative. If we had a point at which $U(t_0)>-B(t_0)$, then we shall always have $U(t)>-B(t)$, and moreover $U$ shall be monotonic increasing. This is a problem however, since now all $t<t_0$ will have $-B(t)<U(t)\leq U(t_0)$ and thus $B(t)>-U(t_0)$. This implies that $B(t)$ is bounded below by $-U(t_0)$, in the limit of $t\to-\infty$, but the Wiener process is almost surely not bounded below. A similar phenomenon happens in the case where $U$ is monotonic decreasing.

Despite the above problems, we can still prove that for any point $(x,y)$ obeying $y+B(x)\neq 0$, there exists a unique local solution to the problem $U'=1/(B+U)$ with initial condition $U(x)=y$. Moreover, the domain of $U$ can be extended to an interval where, at the boundaries (if there are any), we shall have $|U'(t)|\to \infty$. It follows that the solution $U$ we find is both unique and maximal, relative to the $(x,y)$ initial value pair.
To get a unique local solution, consider the modified ODE given by $U' = \min\{\max\{1/(B+U),-C\},C\}$ with initial condition $U(x)=y$, where $C>0$ is some arbitrary constant. The solution to this ODE necessarily exists, and is unique relative to the triplet $(x,y,C)$, so we can let $U_C$ denote that unique solution. Since we presume $B(x)+y \neq 0$, selecting $C > 1/|B(x)+y|$ guarantees the existence of some interval neighborhood of $t=x$ within which $|B(x)+U_C| > 1/C$. By restricting to that neighborhood, we thus have $U_C' = 1/(B+U_C)$, since the minimum and maximum change nothing. This gives a local solution to our original ODE. To get the maximal solution, we just need to be more precise about the domain of $U_C$. For each $C>1/|B(x)+y|$, define the following values.
$$\mu_C = \inf\{t>x : |U_C'(t)|\geq C\}$$
$$\ell_C = \sup\{t<x : |U_C'(t)|\geq C\}$$
Stated simply, the interval $(\ell_C,\mu_C)$ is guaranteed to be the largest interval neighborhood of $x$ within which $U_C' = 1/(B+U_C)$. As a remark, notice that if $\mu_C<\infty$ then necessarily $|U_C'(\mu_C)| = C$, with a similar phenomenon at the $\ell_C$ lowerbound. More importantly, notice that for any two values $C_1<C_2$ and any input $t$ within the intersection of the $(\ell_{C_j},\mu_{C_j})$ intervals, the following necessarily holds.
$$U_{C_1}' = 1/(B+U_{C_1}) = \max\{\min\{1/(B+U_{C_1}), C_2\}, -C_2\}$$
In other words, the $C_1$ solution obeys exactly the ODE which the $C_2$ solution is supposed to satisfy uniquely. It follows that $U_{C_1}(t) = U_{C_2}(t)$ for any $t$ in the aforementioned intersection of intervals. In the case where $\mu_{C_1}<\infty$, this almost immediately implies $\mu_{C_1}<\mu_{C_2}$, and similarly $\ell_{C_2}<\ell_{C_1}$. It follows that in the limit of $C\to\infty$, we have $\mu_C$ monotonic increasing and $\ell_C$ monotonic decreasing.
Finally, we can define $\mu=\lim_{C\to\infty} \mu_C$ and similarly $\ell=\lim_{C\to\infty} \ell_C$, and then define $U$ as the union of the restrictions of the $U_C$ solutions to their intervals $(\ell_C,\mu_C)$. The domain of $U$ is exactly the open interval $(\ell,\mu)$, within which we have $U' = 1/(B+U)$ and also $U(x)=y$. This solution $U$ is maximal in the sense that $|U'(t)|\to \infty$ whenever $t$ approaches a boundary. To prove that, in the case where $\mu<\infty$, we have the $\mu_C$ sequence on which $|U'(C)| = C$ which diverges with $C\to \infty$, hence we have convergence $U(\mu_C)+B(\mu_C) \to 0$ which implies $U(\mu_C) \to -B(\mu)$. Since $U$ is monotonic however, having convergence on a subsequence simply implies convergence, therefore $U(t) \to -B(\mu)$ in the limit of $t\to \mu^-$, and that implies $|U'(t)| \to \infty$. There's a similar argument to prove divergence at the $\ell$ lowerbound.
